# unable to position div at bottom of another div

Tags: html, css

Am trying to position div in bottom of another div but unable to do that

```
        <div class="div">
            <img src="dual.png"/>
            <h1>Boot From a CD or USB Drive on Any PC</h1>
            <div>footers</div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.div{
        float:left;
        height:300px;
        width:22%;
        margin-top:15px;
        margin-left:15px;
        background-color: #e4f2ff
    }
    .div img{
        width:100%;
        height:180px;
    }
    .div h1{
        font-size:20px
    }
    .div div{
        background:red;
        float: bottom;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

here is

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1raqvc8/)

trying to make design like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdGKY.png
Can someone help me how to position div at bottom of parent div..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display:table could help you : http://jsfiddle.net/j1raqvc8/4/

```css
.div {
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    width:22%;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    background-color: #e4f2ff;
    display:table;
}
.div img {
    width:100%;
    height:180px;
}
.div h1 {
    font-size:20px;
    margin:0
}
.div div {
    background:red;
    display:table-footer-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
    <img src="dual.png" />
     <h1>Boot From a CD or USB Drive on Any PC</h1>
    <div>footers</div>
</div>
```

But it will allow the box to grow taller than 300px if content needs more height http://jsfiddle.net/j1raqvc8/5/ .

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute solve your problem.

Note: also try to make your class name more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This also depends how you want it to flow. But since you had absolute in there I went with that.

Add `position: relative;` to the parent.

Take your `float: bottom;` (no such thing) away from the footer div.

```css
.div {
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 22%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background-color: #e4f2ff;
  position: relative;
}
.div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
.div h1 {
  font-size: 20px
}
.div div {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <img src="dual.png" />
  <h1>Boot From a CD or USB Drive on Any PC</h1>

  <div>footers</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sanoj It may not work as you want it to due to it being absolute positioned. If you have any problems come back and we can help. If this is the correct answer please accept it. Thanks.

Comment: without making it absolute position how can i do that

Comment: @Sanoj You should have some sort of flow to your div. Image has x height,  title has x height etc. Push the div down using the elements above.

Answer (score 0):

Delete

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
float: bottom;
```

From Css selector

```
.div div{
```

So it would be like:

```
.div div{
    background:red;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you got several failures in your code. as a suggestion **never** name a `div` class `div`, furthermore there is no `float: bottom`.

you need to add a `position: relative` to the parent element to use `position: absolute` in a child element.

```css
.top{
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    width:22%;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    background-color: #e4f2ff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.div img{
    width:100%;
    height:180px;
}
.div h1{
    font-size:20px
}
.footer {
    background:red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <img src="dual.png"/>
    <h1>Boot From a CD or USB Drive on Any PC</h1>
    <div class="footer">footers</div>
</div>
```